# How to apply css to 3 items after every 3 items?

Tags: html, css

I want to apply different css on every set of 3 items after every 3 items.
Like: i want [1,2,3] to have CSS class1 [4,5,6] to have CSS class2, then again for [7,8,9] CSS class1.

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

i want to apply this styling at few sections where i need this on both `nth-of-type` and `nth-child`. 
i have tried `li:nth-child(5n),li:nth-child(5n-1)` but it only takes 2 elements after every 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is this you are looking for?

```css
li:nth-child(3n-1),
li:nth-child(3n-2),
li:nth-child(3n-3){
  background: red;
}
li:nth-child(6n),
li:nth-child(6n-1),
li:nth-child(6n-2){
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: YES!  will it work with n number of items ?

Comment: Yes, it should work with any number of items. Mine was a slighty different version but the same idea, unfortunately I was too slow: https://jsfiddle.net/8hmpwaf7/2/

Comment: Sure, I have doubled the <li> count to 24 in the answer. just check.

Comment: I am bit confused with formula. yours and @arkuuu works same. can you explain a little?

Comment: the first css rule can be made more simple like li{background: red;}. This will set background color to red for all <li>.  the second rule is over writing the first one for specific <li>s. the selectors are 6n=6th, 12th, 18th etc.. 6n-1= 5th, 11th, 17th etc and 6n-2=4th, 10th, 16th..

Comment: My version takes every element and divides it's index by 6. If the rest is 1,2,3 it is in the first group, if it is 4,5,6 (6 would be the same as no rest) it is in second group.

Comment: will it work with `nth-of-type` ?