# Background color for UL element didn't work

Tags: html, css, forms, sass, scss-mixins

I want to highlight every 2 rows alternately like the image below

[image: sample ouput]

but I can't make it work using UL element. Here is code https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Please post some code or working jsfiddle.

Comment: here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/p34a7gst/

Comment: There is a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574272/how-to-apply-css-to-3-items-after-every-3-items

Comment: just add------------- ul {
    height: 18px;
    margin: 0px;
} ----------  in your css          it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` for `UL` because your `li` is `floating`

```
ul{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```css
ul{
  overflow:hidden;
}
li{
    height: 10px;
    width: 32.33%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}

 ul:nth-child(4n), ul:nth-child(4n-1){
  background: gray;
  color: red;

}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>20</li>
    <li>21</li>
    <li>22</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>23</li>
    <li>24</li>
    <li>25</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>20</li>
    <li>21</li>
    <li>22</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>23</li>
    <li>24</li>
    <li>25</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi @Lalji Tadhani, I created a custom class and put in UL element it didn't work. Here is the sample code https://jsfiddle.net/Lq51btxo/

Comment: check now https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/hvL93zc2/1/ your target is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have to target the `li` inside `ul`

```
ul:nth-child(4n) li, ul:nth-child(4n-1) li{
  background: gray;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(4n), tr:nth-child(4n-1){
  background: gray;
  color: red;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Striped Table</h2>
<p>For zebra-striped tables, use the nth-child() selector and add a background-color to all even (or odd) table rows:</p>

<table>
  <tr>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Peter</td>
  <td>Griffin</td>
  <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Lois</td>
  <td>Griffin</td>
  <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Joe</td>
  <td>Swanson</td>
  <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Cleveland</td>
  <td>Brown</td>
  <td>$250</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Cleveland</td>
  <td>Brown</td>
  <td>$250</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Cleveland</td>
  <td>Brown</td>
  <td>$250</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Cleveland</td>
  <td>Brown</td>
  <td>$250</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hope it help you out..